# How to stop my laptop's screen from rotating when I press Alt + Arrow?

Tags: laptop, thinkpad

I have a [ThinkPad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThinkPad) laptop, and whenever I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left arrow</kbd>, my screen rotates to the left. How do I stop this annoying behavior?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to an answer on [this post](http://forum.tabletpcreview.com/lenovo-ibm/17069-how-disable-screen-orientation-hotkeys-ctrl-alt-arrow.html) on TabletPCReview.com:

> Do a CTL + ALT + F12.
>
> This will bring up the Intel control panel. Goto 'Hot Keys' tab and
> uncheck the box 'Enable Hot Keys'.

The "Hot Keys" tab is under "Options and Support".

However, a further post indicates that there are other keys that rotate the screen that don't get disabled by this method.