# Disable Alt + Arrow display flip keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows-7, hotkeys, nvidia-graphics-card

Whenever I click <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow up</kbd>/<kbd>Arrow down</kbd> my screen will do an unwanted flip. I'd like to disable this shortcut behaviour. I've already looked at Super User question *[How to stop my laptop's screen from rotating when I press Alt + Arrow?](https://superuser.com/questions/214123)*.

But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> doesn't start any menu for me. How can I fix this problem?

I have an Nvidia graphic card, 2100M, and Windows 7 on a Toshiba computer.

Comment: One of the **worst shortcuts ever**, which is confusing so many users who hit those keys accidentially and do not know how to get back to the default view.

Comment: One of the most accessible shortcuts assigned to the least used feature. When was the last time you needed to rotate your screen on Laptop/Desktop?

Comment: @jerrymouse Well don't you just love to sit and play a game and make it harder by rotating the screen while you play >_<

Comment: @jerrymouse I rotate my screen regularly on my desktop, since I like to use portrait for reading webpages, documents and for coding.  Try it sometime (if you have a screen that can rotate) - it will change your life!  When was the last time you wrote in a physical notebook in landscape format? - it doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some obscure place off the internet I found a solution.

Run **msconfig** (<kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>), select **startup** and disable `Toshiba 180 Degrees Rotation Utility`; then, click **Apply** and  finally **OK**.

Answer (score 229):

Neither of these answers helped me. What I did:

Right-click on Desktop and select Graphics options > hotkeys > Disable

As indicated in [Windows Forums](http://windowsforums.org/topic/5365-disabling-ctrlaltarrow-rotate-screen/) and [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/ctrlaltarrowsflipping-my-screen-sideways-and/ed43c561-eef3-4934-b5c9-95a91d62d184)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I needed to assign other hotkeys in the Intel Graphics options dialog.

Comment: Note to future readers: This does not seem to interfere with Windows shortcuts as I was fearing it might.

Comment: remipod is correct (see also Noxoreos's answer): You need to assign different shortcuts in the Intel thing, otherwise it still intercepts the keypresses and other programs can't use them.

Comment: Worked on Windows 8.1 

Comment: still works in Windows 10

Comment: works for me. window 10 pro. 2019.

Comment: In Windows 10 this works, and also releases the control-alt-arrow hotkeys back to your app :-)

Comment: I did as you mentioned, did `Alt + left arrow` to verify, did `Alt + Right arrow` and upvoted your answer. (y)

Answer (score 84):

For these using Intel Graphic, to disable global hotkeys:

- Right click on your Desktop and select:

[image]

Comment: Normally, I am able to access the Intel Graphics from the system tray, but it was disabled for some reason. I was trying to raise and lower the volume on WinAmp, but it kept flipping the screen!

Comment: thx @dario , upvoted for saving my day :)

Answer (score 11):

I had the exact same issue on an Acer notebook with an Intel graphics driver. Simply disabling the feature was not enough, since the keys are still captured and not passed to the system afterwards, even if the rotation did not happen.

That means I was still not able to use this key combination in any other software, because it won't receive the shortcut.

To solve this I opened the Intel graphics properties page, enabled shortcuts, changed all available shortcuts from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+*(some key)* to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+*(some key)*, and finally deactivated it again.
This way the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> combination is captured only for the <kbd>F8</kbd> key, which can't be changed, and all other shortcuts are captured by the software I wanted to use (like Eclipse or PHPStorm) - I rarely use the other combination, so this was a valid solution for me.

Comment: Perfect. I needed to do this to enable the `ctrl`+`alt`+`<-` and `ctrl`+`alt`+`->` shortcuts for changing tab in RStudio.

Answer (score 6):

1. Press Ctrl + Alt + F12
2. Click on "Options and Support"
3. You can now either disable the hotkeys or change the keys.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the Control Panel for the Nvidia Desktop Software and launch it. It should bring up a configuration Menu (for screen resolution, etc.) and there should be a Menu Item to disable the Hotkeys. 
IIRC it is the last Item.

Comment: Will try to look at work tommorow, I've looked before but couldn't find it. Its a mobile graphic card NVS 2100M.

Comment: I really can't find it. I've looked inside the nvidia control panel under display -> change resolution and display -> rotate display.

Answer (score 4):

If your processor is from Intel, one of these possibilities should work in your case:

1. Right-click on your desktop background and
   select **Graphics Options** > **Hot Keys** > **Disable**
   as illustrated in [dario's answer](https://superuser.com/a/768781/112297).
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to open an Intel dialog box and disable the **Hot Keys**. You may have to change the shortcuts before disabling them as explained in the [Noxoreos' answer](https://superuser.com/a/851608/112297). [image: Panneau de configuration graphique et média Intel]
3. Temporary stop process **hkcmd** using **Task manager** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>) as proposed in the [gavenkoa's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1236803/112297). You may also stop the process **igfxTray** as suggested by [gavenkoa](https://superuser.com/u/49345). But on next reboot, this (these) process(es) will start again.
4. Disable the starting of **hkcmd** (and **igfxTray**):

   - <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
   - enter **msconfig**
   - go to tab **Startup**
   - uncheck `C:\windows\system32\hkcmd.exe`
   - (and also uncheck `igfxtray.exe`).

[image: Window of msconfig.exe]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to disable hot key catching by Intel applet (by <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F12</kbd> or from *Graphic options* on Desktop right click).

But I recommend to disable Intel applets!

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Esc</kbd> to start Task Manager and disable everything published  Intel in *Startup* tab (`hkcmd module` is responsible for catching keys, also `igfxTray module` is useless).

Answer (score 1):

### To free up the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>*Arrow*</kbd> shortcuts for VS Code's multiple cursors

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> to open the Intel Graphics hotkeys window
2. Click inside the hotkey fields and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>NEWLETTER</kbd> to reassign each one. I recommend using the letters **D I S A B L E** to make it clear to your future self that you deliberately disabled the functionality:

[image]

Click Apply.

3. Uncheck the Enable checkbox to disable the hotkeys entirely. Click Apply.

**You should now be able to trigger VS Code's multiple cursors using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>*Up/Down*</kbd> (and anything else that requires <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>*Arrow*</kbd> combinations).**