# How can I re-enable backspace navigation in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

The latest version of Google Chrome has changed the hotkey for 'back' from <kbd>backspace</kbd> to **<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>backspace</kbd>**.  The new combination doesn't work on my laptop, however I would actually rather stick with the older key anyway.

I've read in other questions that Chrome doesn't allow you to customise shortcuts, however is there any way to either re-enable the original shortcut or to override it back to being just backspace?

[image: Chrome screenshot]

I'm running Windows 10.

Comment: For windows, [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/back-to-backspace/cldokedgmomhbifmiiogjjkgffhcbaec).

Comment: The new hotkey (Alt+Left) is bad because I can't easily press it with one hand,

Comment: Please note that only left alt + <- works. Pressing right alt will rotate the screen.

Comment: @DanielShatz that is completely inaccurate, right alt works just fine

Comment: Doesn't work on my old pc.. Probably keyboard layout dependent. @GL_Stephen

Comment: @DanielShatz The right-alt shortcut rotating your screen is probably something specific to your system. It appears to be a feature provided by the graphics drivers on some laptops. See these two questions: http://superuser.com/questions/214123/how-to-stop-my-laptops-screen-from-rotating-when-i-press-alt-arrow http://superuser.com/questions/373832/disable-alt-arrow-display-flip-keyboard-shortcut

Comment: Yes, you are right. I already found that setting in Intel Graphics options. @Frungi

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Google has now published an official extension: '[Go Back With Backspace](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/go-back-with-backspace/eekailopagacbcdloonjhbiecobagjci)', to re-enable the backspace button as the hotkey for 'back'.

> **Re-enables the backspace key as a back navigation button (except when
>   writing text). Go back with the backspace button! This extension
>   re-enables the backspace key as a back navigation button -- except if
>   you're writing text.**
>
> Before Chrome 52, the backspace key navigated back (if you weren't
>   writing text). Many people lost their progress while working online by
>   accidentally pressing backspace and leaving a page -- so we removed
>   the feature from Chrome, and created this extension for those who
>   prefer the old behavior.
>
> This extension can't restore backspace on certain special pages, for
>   example any of the "chrome://" pages such as Settings or Extensions.
>
> About the "all sites" permission: In order to capture backspace on
>   every page, the extension needs to install a little piece of code on
>   each one. It does nothing else with the the page, its information, or
>   your typing.

Source: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=608016

Answer (score 21):

It isn't working for you because, confusingly, it isn't <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, it's actually <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> (the left arrow key).

Comment: Oh!  Am I the only one who would have interpreted that as backspace?!

Comment: @Rory Absolutely not, lol. I work with computers for a living, and I sat here pressing ALT+Backspace over and over again, thinking, "WHY WON'T YOU WORK?!" :P (Thanks for the solution, Sam!)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to maintain the old shortcut without adding an extension, add this CLI command to your Google Chrome link (right-click shortcut > Properties > "Target"):

```
--enable-blink-features=BackspaceDefaultHandler --test-type
```

So in my case, the target becomes:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --enable-blink-features=BackspaceDefaultHandler --test-type`

Credit to [Mattias](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-52-return-old-backspace-behaviour/)

Comment: And naturally this *flag* doesn't appear in `chrome://flags`

Comment: This flag seems to have disappeared now? Chrome v. 54.0.2840.99 m

Comment: I just tested it on Version 54.0.2840.99 m. It still works.
NB it only applied the flag to the shortcut. So if I add the flag to the link in my taskbar, it will work if I left-click on that icon to launch Chrome. If I right click on the icon and then click "New Window" it doesn't seem to work. I guess it is a different shortcut.

Comment: Yes, I tested at home and it works there. Don't know what is wrong with my work computer.

Answer (score 1):

[The *Backspace to go Back* extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/backspace-to-go-back/nlffgllnjjkheddehpolbanogdeaogbc) reverts to the pre-52 chrome behavior that you want.

Comment: Just what I need - another extension to slow down my browser!

Comment: You can use [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/1113193/9825)'s solution.